# Add a delay to a preloader gif

Tags: javascript

I want to add a delay to a preloader gif. I followed this http://www.netavatar.co.in/2011/05/31/how-to-show-a-loading-gif-image-while-a-page-loads-using-javascript-and-css/ tutorial and got it to work but I want to display the loading gif for a minimum of 3 seconds as the page loads.

Thanks for you help

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
        function preloader(){
            document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("content").style.display = "block";
        }//preloader
        window.onload = preloader;
// ]]></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `setTimeout`?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    function preloader(){
        setTimeout(function() {
          document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById("content").style.display = "block";
        }, 3000);
    }//preloader
    window.onload = preloader;
 // ]]></script>
```

Above will show loading for the loading time and for the next 3 seconds. If you want to achieve something like "show loading for at least 3 seconds, but hide immediately when loaded if loading took longer than 3 seconds", than you can use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    var minimumShowLoadingTimeReached = false;
    setTimeout(function() {minimumShowLoadingTimeReached = true;}, 3000);

    function preloader() {
      if (minimumShowLoadingTimeReached) {
          showContent();
      } else {
          setTimeout(function() {
            preloader();
          }, 500);
      }
    }

    function showContent(){
        document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("content").style.display = "block";
    }
    window.onload = preloader;
// ]]></script>
```

How it works?

1. if the page loads in less then 3 seconds - show the loading block for 3-3.5 seconds
2. if the page loads in more than 3 seconds (e.g. in 4 seconds) - show the loading block just for the loading time (with the accuracy of half a second)

Comment: I actually like this one better than my answer

Comment: Thanks for help, the delay is working but it now breaking my slider on my wordpress site.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
  function preloader(secs){
    if (secs >= 3) {
      document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("content").style.display = "block";
    } else {
      setTimeout(function(){preloader(secs+1);},1000);
    }
  }
  window.onload = preloader(0);
// ]]></script>
```

---

1. This sends a number (number of seconds) along when invoking preloader().
2. In preloader the if-clause checks whether the number has reached '3'.
3. If not, the preloader() invokes itself again after a timeout of a second (1000ms).
4. When 'secs' has reached 3, the code to hide the loader and show the content is executed.